# Conditional expectation problem 2

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X_{1},...,X_{n}$ be i.i.d. random variables such that $E|X_{i}|< \infty$ for $i=1,..,n$. Consider the sigma-algebra $ \mathcal{G}=\sigma(X_{1}+...+X_{n})$. I have to show that $E(X_{i}|\mathcal{G})=E(X_{1}|\mathcal{G})$ for $i=1,..n$ . I suspect that I should use the definition of the conditional expectation and take advantage of the sigma-algebra stucture, but I can not figure out the way. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of Conditional Expectation, $Y=E(X_{1}|\mathcal{G})$ if the following conditions holds:

1. $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable,
2. $E\left[Y\cdot\mathbf{1}_{G}\right]=E\left[X_1\cdot\mathbf{1}_{G}\right]$ for any $G\in \mathcal G$, where $\mathbf{1}_{G}$ is indicator function.

Let us check whether $Y=E(X_{1}|\mathcal{G})$ coincide with $E(X_{i}|\mathcal{G})$. We need to check conditions similar to 1,2.

1. $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable,
2. $E\left[Y\cdot\mathbf{1}_{G}\right]=E\left[X_i\cdot\mathbf{1}_{G}\right]$ for any $G\in \mathcal G$.

The first condition is satisfied automatically. To check 2nd, one need to prove only that $E\left[X_i\cdot\mathbf{1}_{G}\right]=E\left[X_1\cdot\mathbf{1}_{G}\right]$ for any $G\in \mathcal G$.

Remind that any set $G\in\mathcal G$ has the form $G=\{X_1+\ldots+X_n\in B\}$ for some Borel $B$.

Since $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d., distributions of random vectors 
$$(X_1,\ldots,X_i,\ldots,X_n) \text{ and } (X_i,\ldots,X_1,\ldots,X_n)$$
are the same (both are products of the same marginal distributions). And the distributions of any measurable function of the first vector is the same as the distribution of this function of the second vector. Therefore
$$X_i\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{X_1+\ldots+X_n\in B\}}\overset{d}{=}X_1\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\{X_1+\ldots+X_n\in B\}}$$ for any $B\in\mathfrak B(\mathbb R)$ and their expectations coincide:
$$E\left[X_i\cdot\mathbf{1}_{G}\right]\equiv E\left[X_1\cdot\mathbf{1}_{G}\right] $$

We check that $Y=E(X_{1}|\mathcal{G})$ satisfies the definition of $E(X_{i}|\mathcal{G})$. Then $$Y=E(X_{1}|\mathcal{G})=E(X_{i}|\mathcal{G}) \text{ a.s.}$$

Comment: The way to go. +1.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending the time to write a full answer! The measurable function that you use is the product of the projection to the first coordinate with the indicator function of G right? Forgive me if it's a trivial question. @NCh

Comment: @gauss134 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

A physicist would use an argument by symmetry -- all $X_i$ are iid, and you are conditioning on the symmetric events, so how could you possibly tell any difference between any of the individual random variables? Not only expected values, but variances, etc etc would be the same.

Comment: And a mathematician would turn this (excellent) heuristics into a solid mathematical proof. Did you?

Comment: @Did that would require doing my work for the OP. My job is to give him a push -- his job is to do something worthwhile... which I cannot say for the accepted answer...

Comment: Of course the whole question is whether you gave any mathematical push at all... But anyway, what is your beef with the accepted answer? Please be specific.

Comment: @Did he did everything for the OP -- even chewed and swallowed. I rarely prefer to write complete answers like this for the sake of making OP do *something* for his problem...

Comment: Hmmm... Except that, conditional expectation being a notoriously confusing subject because people do not learn the relevant definitions, there is no chance that your answer could lead the OP to a solution. My take on this situation is that either one should close the question for lack of context, or address it similarly to what the accepted answer provides (that is, basically by recalling the relevant definitions). What you posted might be amounting to trying to stay in the middle...

Comment: The first solution is not really that creative and has little positive effect. I am trying to get the OP would reply to my answer showing some small work so I can then push him further. This strategy often pays off better than dismissing the questions, and giving out the whole thing in one shot is an unlikely way to teach people the definitions... But either way, I did not downvote the accepted answer -- all are entitled to their own opinions how to better teach people